# Is there an iOS application to search photos near my location?

Tags: ios, photography, maps, geo-location

I was trying to find photos near my location, maybe the ones related to particular keywords or tags, also wanted to be able to do this from my mobile device.

It would be great if it allows to search from the most popular sharing sites (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, Flickr, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I belive this one is worth a look
[Layar](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/layar-augmented-reality/id334404207?mt=8)

It can see geotagged photos from Panoramio and Wikipedia.